# How can I authenticate using a github token in Travis-CI APIv3?

Tags: travis-ci, travis-ci-api

In the Travis-CI APIs v2 and v2.1 there was an option to generate a Travis API token using a github API token. However, this Travis token is incompatible with Travis APIv3 and will give a 403 error.

Is there a way to:

a) generate a Travis-CI APIv3 token using a github token or

b) convert an APIv2.x token to an APIv3 token

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9273

Seems like it is not support yet. Using V2 seems to be the solution for now.